# Flash: component to library directly

Tags: flash

I'm starting with programming actionscript and have a simple flow question related to flash. When I want to add a component to my library for later use with AS, I usually have to add the component to the canvas first so I can convert it to symbol. I then delete the Component instance from the canvas and bring instead the Symbol instance I just created.

Is there a way to go from component to library directly without having to drag a component instance first to the canvas (since that component instance would have to be deleted anyway and replaced with a symbol isntance once the symbol has been created)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried dragging the component directly to your library?